# SqlDataReader and SqlCommand using SUM()

Tags: c#, sql

I have a simple query which sums a column in a table from SQL database when a condition is met.

```
decimal stock = 0;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader myRdr;
cmd.Connection = connection;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT SUM(stock) AS stock FROM table WHERE id=@id AND condition=@condition";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = id;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@condition", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = condition;

connection.Open();
myRdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (myRdr.HasRows)
{
    myRdr.Read();
    stock += Convert.ToDecimal(myRdr1["stock"]);
}

myRdr1.Close();
cmd1.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

It works ok if there are entries in the table that meet the condition. If there are no entries, it throws an exception saying I try to convert DBNull type to decimal, which is not possible. I tried it like this:

```
if (myRdr.HasRows)
{
    myRdr.Read();
    if (myRdr["stock"] != null)
    {
        stock += Convert.ToDecimal(myRdr1["stock"]);
    }
}
```

But it still throws an exception. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your query a bit from this:

```
SELECT SUM(stock) AS stock
FROM table
WHERE id=@id AND condition=@condition
```

to this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(stock, 0) AS stock
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(stock) AS stock
    FROM table
    WHERE id=@id AND condition=@condition
) q
```

Comment: Used your solution with one little addition: SELECT ISNULL(stock, 0) AS stock FROM...

Answer (score 3):

`myRdr1["stock"]` is returning a `DBNull`, so check for that instead of `null`.

```
if (myRdr1["stock"] != DBNull)
{
    stock += Convert.ToDecimal(myRdr1["stock"]);
}
```

Comment: You can always embed SUM(stock) in COALESCE: COALESCE(SUM(stock), 0) this way it will return 0 then there is no stock.

Comment: True, it might be best to have the fix on the client AND server though